# Autocomplete Rails it is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, autocomplete

What did I do wrong in this tutorial: https://github.com/grosser/simple_auto_complete

Here are my scripts by the way:

First I put this in my **users_controller.rb**

```
autocomplete_for :user, :username, :limit => 15, :order => 'created_at DESC'
```

In my routes.rb

```
namespace :profile do

  resources :users, :only => [:index] do 
    collection do
      post "search"
      get "autocomplete_for_user_name"
  end
end
```

In my application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .

//= require jquery.autocomplete.js

//= require jquery.js

jQuery(function($){//on document ready
    //autocomplete
    $('input.autocomplete').each(function(){
        var input = $(this);
        input.autocomplete(input.attr('data-autocomplete-url'),{
            matchContains:1,//also match inside of strings when caching
            //    mustMatch:1,//allow only values from the list
            //    selectFirst:1,//select the first item on tab/enter
            removeInitialValue:0//when first applying $.autocomplete
        });
    });
});
```

In my views (app/views/profile/messages/compose.html.haml)

```
%div#page-info
  %span#title
    Compose
  %span#desc
    Compose a new Message

= form_for :message, :url => send_message_profile_messages_path do |message|
  %label{:for => "friend"} To:
  %br
  =message.text_field :auto_user_name , :class => 'autocomplete', 'data-autocomplete-url'=> autocomplete_for_user_name_profile_users_path

  %script{:type => "text/javascript"}jQuery(function($){//on document ready $('input.autocomplete').each(function(){var $input = $(this);$input.autocomplete($input.attr('data-autocomplete-url'));});});

  //= collection_select(:message, :friend_id, @friends, :id, :username)
  %br
  %label{:for => "message"} Body:
  %br
  = message.text_area :message
  %br
  = message.file_field :attachment
  %br
  = submit_tag "Send", :confirm => "Are you sure?"
```

I am trying to autocomplete the users using their username (s)

Note: I had also installed the gem and I think there's no problem about that.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: are you getting any javascript errors in firebug console?

Comment: have you added called the javascript

Comment: what do you mean by called javascript @PriteshJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In view 
remove the comment `//on document ready` from `script`, as it is all in single line I think it is commenting the whole line including js code.

or use alternate formatting

```
:javascript
  //on document ready
  jQuery(function($){
    $('input.autocomplete').each(function(){
      var $input = $(this);
      $input.autocomplete($input.attr('data-autocomplete-url'));
    });
  });
```

add `//= require_self` to application file for adding its own js code.

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
//= require jquery.autocomplete.js
//= require jquery.js 

jQuery(function($){//on document ready
    //autocomplete
    $('input.autocomplete').each(function(){
        var input = $(this);
        input.autocomplete(input.attr('data-autocomplete-url'),{
            matchContains:1,//also match inside of strings when caching
            //    mustMatch:1,//allow only values from the list
            //    selectFirst:1,//select the first item on tab/enter
            removeInitialValue:0//when first applying $.autocomplete
        });
    });
});
```

Also try not to have white spaces between require.
rails warning in application.js says

```
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
```

I have been using this autocomplete it works great for me
https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete